# JQuery animate maximum speed

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, max

Is it possible to let, when doing an animate, the speed of the animation only go to a maximum amount. So it should accerlate as normal and when the speed hits a certain value it should stay at this maximum speed.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds much like an easing problem, but barring the math and the tech know-how on making one yourself, you always have the option to chain two animations sequentially.

```
$('#foo')
    .animate({ /* start off the animation */ }, 1000, 'swing')
    .animate({ /* finish the animation */ }, 1000, 'linear')
    ;
```

... or something similar.

Keep in mind that animations on the same (element) queue, while animations on different ones run parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Max animation speed is controlled by the distance the animation must move, the duration of the animation and the easing function (where should it accelerate/decelerate).  The simplest example would be with a linear easing (constant speed).  In that case, the speed in pixels/sec would just be the total pixel distance the animation moves divided by the duration of the animation in seconds.  You control both of those parameters (duration and distance) so you can set it how you like.

For non-linear animations, the overall sense of speed is still determined by distance and duration, but the exact acceleration/deceleration within that duration interval is determined by the easing function.  Easing functions take a little getting used to in order to build your own, but there are lots already built.

jQuery has two easing functions built-in called `"swing"` and `"linear"`.  There are many, many other easing functions already built that you can pick from include the ones in [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) and various third party easing functions like [these](http://jqueryeasing.com/).